# SLD specification for a vertical line on every line turning point

Tags: openlayers-2, symbology, sld, line

You can define a vertical line in SLD like this:

```
   <LineSymbolizer>
     <Stroke>
       <GraphicStroke>
         <Graphic>
           <Mark>
             <WellKnownName>shape://vertline</WellKnownName>
             <Stroke>
               <CssParameter name="stroke">#333333</CssParameter>
               <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
             </Stroke>
           </Mark>
           <Size>12</Size>
         </Graphic>
       </GraphicStroke>
     </Stroke>
   </LineSymbolizer>
```

There is no definition in xml for the place of that vertical line. I am making a solution for OpenLayers like in [[1]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49722/how-to-use-a-sld-file-with-openlayers-using-osm-data) but cannot figure out, how to place the vertical lines across the long line that goes horizontally.

Adding to OpenLayers goes similar to:

```
var format = new OpenLayers.Format.SLD();
OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: "yoursldfile.sld",
    success: sldparser
});
function sldparser(req) {
    sld = format.read(req.responseXML || req.responseText);
    styles = sld.namedLayers.interpreted.userStyles[0];
    building_vec.styleMap.styles.default = styles;
}
```

I would like to add the vertical lines to places, where the continuous line makes a tilt to new direction.

**Question:**

How to tell the place of vertical lines in the combo of Openlayers and sld?

**More specifically:**

How to tell it is in the turning point of straight line?

**With picture:**

[image]

I want the vertical "railroad hatches" to appear only in places, where the "railroad" changes direction. [[2]](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html#railroad-hatching)

**My source:**

[1] [How to use a sld file with Openlayers using OSM data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49722/how-to-use-a-sld-file-with-openlayers-using-osm-data)

[2] http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html#railroad-hatching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`vertices` function](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/geometry-transformations.html#extracting-vertices) might help you, as documented in the GeoServer manual. I used this to show cadastral survey points.